# unwanted extra space between element and its borders

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I would like to ask somebody if can help me with following problem:
On screen bellow there is a space between element and border:

[image: borders1]

if i will change top position to 0, it looks like this:

[image: borders2]

This extra space appears in Chrome and Opera, in Firefox it's fine
This is probably due to a different calculation in the browsers.
I have in Chrome magnification of 100%, but if I set the magnification
for example to 110%, the display of the element is fine (without space)

I want to achieve that there will be no space in all browsers at 100% magnification.
Is there any way to do this with javascript or css?

I tried to change css properties, f.e.  display from flex to block, change box-sizing
of element and its childs (header, footer, content)... but the problem
described was not solved.

I can offcourse create borders width boxshadow instead, maybe it can be solved
with pseudo elements, but that's not what I want.

```css
.modal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 30px;
  border-color: #000000;
  background-color: yellow;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.header,
.footer {
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
  background-color: orange;
  width: 380px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.content {
  background-color: #bd0bae;
  width: 400px;
  height: 320px;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header,
.footer,
.content {
  margin: 0;
  border-width: 0;
  border: none;
  border-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="modal" class="modal">
  <div id="header" class="header">header</div>
  <div id="content" class="content">content</div>
  <div id="footer" class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

Many thanks in advance for any comment.

Comment: at the top of CSS, try adding `* { margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;}` to reset the CSS

Comment: This is typical when the page is zoomed in, You however say you aren't applying any zoom, on the other hand I can't see what you're seeing unless i zooming, So i'm not really sure about your claims. And if it's a zooming problem it shouldn't be any of your concern.

Comment: frozen, thanks for comment, I have tried, nothing has changed, it doesn't solve it

Comment: Thanks Zohir for comment. It may be a matter of zoom, offcourse. But  I have zoom in Chrome set to  100 % , and I see the result as it is on screen enclosed in post.  If I have such a problem and zoom is 100%, other users may see the same result as well.  Therefore, I want to find out what causes it and whether it is possible to solve it.